# How to match Enumerations in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have multiple enum objects as follows (these are just examples):

```
object Status extends Enumeration {
  val Pending, Done = Value
}

object Gender extends Enumeration {
  val Female, Male, Other = Value
}

...
```

And, I want to match any object extending `Enumeration`. This one works:

```
def func(anyVal: Any): String = anyVal match {
  case strVal: String             => "This is a String"
  case status: Status.Value       => "This is an Enumeration"
  case gender: Gender.Value       => "This is an Enumeration"
  ...
}
```

However, I don't need to match enums separately. Something like this would be great:

```
def func(anyVal: Any): String = anyVal match {
  case strVal: String             => "This is a String"
  case e: Enumeration.Value       => "This is an Enumeration"
}
```

But, this doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with type projection `Enumeration#Value`

```
anyVal match {
  case strVal: String       => "This is a String"
  case e: Enumeration#Value => "This is an Enumeration"
}
```

instead of `Enumeration.Value`. Note `Value` class is a member of `Enumeration` class

```
abstract class Enumeration { 
  ...
  abstract class Value { 
      ...
  }
}
```

so we need type projection to refer to its type.

As a side note, dot notation can only be used if the left-hand side is a value. Also if possible try to avoid `Any` in the design, as in a sense it defeats the strengths of using Scala which is rich type information.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How can I avoid using `Any` if I don't have any constraints for the given parameter? This function is an example but actually, it tries to convert anything into a meaningful String.  So, the function also has a default case like `case other: Any => other.toString`.

Comment: @Alperen you want a **typeclass**: https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html